# Traer imagenes a carousel php PDO

Tags: php

Tengo una pregunta quiero traerme varias imagenes que estan guardadas en my base de datos pero no logro acomodarlas en un corousel alguien me puede ayudar

esto es lo que tengo en la vista pero no logro hacerla funcionar lo estoy haciendo con pdo y php 7 y son 3 imagenes que estan guardadas en mi base de datos

He probado varias cosas pero no me funciona, no se como hacer que me aparezcan las tres imagenes en ese carousel

```html
<?php 

               
          $galeria = json_decode($categorias["imagen_slide"], true);

                 ?>

                 <?php

                 foreach ($galeria as $key => $value): ?>
                     
  <li>  

                 <img  src="<?php echo $value ?>" class="img-fluid">

              
              </li>

         
                  <?php endforeach ?>
```

```html
  <div class="card-body">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=I+Love+Bootstrap" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x500/3c8dbc/ffffff&text=I+Love+Bootstrap" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x500/f39c12/ffffff&text=I+Love+Bootstrap" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-custom-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-custom-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? ¿Las imágenes se están obteniendo? ¿Es el código CSS que no funciona? etc.

Comment: no logro traerlas en el carousel con el foreach

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esta parte:  `foreach ($galeria as $key => $value): ?>`? ¿Haz depurado algo ahí, por ejemplo: `var_dump($value);` o, una depuración más general: `var_dump($galeria);` antes del bucle.